# Visible redirection nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I have a host that looks like this `http://loc.www.site.com:42080` I want when the user access to `http://loc.www.site.com:42080` it  should  be redirected to `http://loc.www.site.com:42080/fr`.

This a part of nginx.conf:

```
location / {

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        include ez_params.d/ez_fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass engine:9000;
        fastcgi_param SYMFONY_ENV dev;
        fastcgi_param RUNNING_ENV DOCKER;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work

```
server {
    listen 42080;
    listen [::]:42080;
    hostname loc.www.site.com;

    location ^/en {
      return 301 http://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to process the redirection only is the user browser lanaguge is en?